# Query to search email id in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, email

I have a query where i need to search for name by its email id.
The email id is stored in a variable.
I have tested the query on MySql console it works fine but not to use the same in PHP.
The query is

`SELECT name FROM user WHERE email='$email'`

My email id format is bit tricky first-name.last-name@domain-name

Please help !

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Post you php code which is executing query

Comment: I don't see any issue with that, just use below query in your PHP script.
$query = "SELECT name FROM user WHERE email= '".$email."'";

Comment: use backtick for USER.... SELECT `name` FROM `user` WHERE `email`='$email' ... or share the code

Comment: Sorry for late reply. There is no error but the ans in the text field is the query & not the username as required

Comment: Check the email id format. Do ull think that can be the issue ?

Answer (score -1):

**NOTE: Don't use `single quotes ('name = $variable_name')` with variables in the string. 

Always Use `Double Quotes ("name =$variable_name")`.**

Try the following query, definitely works for you:

```
$query = "SELECT name FROM user WHERE email=$email";
```

Or better to use like :

```
$query = 'SELECT name FROM user WHERE email="'.$email.'"';
```

Comment: dont know how it works? $query = 'SELECT name FROM user WHERE email='.$email;